# serial-port communication with programmable indicator

Tags: serial-port, scale, indicator

Does anybody have a program manual/documentation for avery weigh-tronix model 1015.Trying to talk to the scale indicator through rs-232. thanks

Comment: Have you tried to contact the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a model 1015 listed, but … http://www.wtxweb.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=23&Itemid=188 ?

In particular, http://www.wtxweb.com/literature/E1110_serialcomm_u_en_76102_743.pdf has the serial protocols. If all else fails, they may be similar?

Comment: Good find. I did some basic searching but couldn't find anything like that.